# Crystal Report Database Fields doesn't display classes from a referenced project

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I created a website and a class library project. The website have a reference to a class library.

I added a new Crystal Report item to the website (*CrystalReport.rpt*), and on the Database Expert screen, in the `Database Fields` section I need to select fields that are members of classes in the class library (referenced project). Only the website classes appear in the list.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, in order to see the DB fields, I had to create the XSD even if I had to populate a dataset and pass it along once in design time (debugging) . Try doing so before adding the rpt file.